# The octonions on a bad day

Tags: octonions, non-associative-algebras

We can define the algebra of quaternions $\mathbb H$ over any field $k$, and depending on the arithmetic of $k$ it is either a division algebra or a matrix algebra.

We can also define the algebra of octonions $\mathbb O$ over any field $k$, and if over $k$ the $8$-ary quadratic form $Q=x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_5^2+x_6^2+x_7^2$ is anisotropic, then $\mathbb O$ is again a division algebra —a non-associative one, but oh well.

> What happens to $\mathbb O$ if $k$ is such that $Q$ is isotropic?

The classical structure theory of non-commutative Jordan algebras tells us that $\mathbb O$ is, over any field, a direct product of simple flexible power-associative algebras coming from a rather restricted list: simple commutative Jordan algebras, quasiassociative algebras, and flexible quadratic algebras with nondegenerate norm forms (Shafer's book on non-associative algebra explains all this, which is —I'd say— mostly forgotten nowadays) but I am pretty sure one can be very specific about what comes out in the case of octonions. In other words, one can probably find something playing the role of «matrix algebra» in the statement about quaternions.

**N.B.** All this is over fields of characteristic zero.

Comment: Of course, we can also «define $\mathbb C$ over any field» and it is also easy to describe its structure depending on the arithmetic of the base field $k$.

Comment: It's times like this that I wish I knew what a Jordan algebra is. 

Comment: I see. Isn't the quadratic form 8-ary?

Comment: Google "octonion algebra" and "split octonion algebra" (analogy: special orthogonal groups for isotropic quadratic forms, or even for a split quadratic form).

Comment: Yeah, it is: that's what I get from counting from zero. I blame the French.

Comment: @pranavk, of course I already googled that :-) But the definitions of split octonions I found are essentially undistinguishable from those of octonions: there *is* a difference of complexity in going from quaternions to matrix algebras, which is not found in going to the split-octonions (at least, in the references to these that I found)

Comment: If you are explaining quaternions to someone and she asks «and what happens if the norm form has non-trivial zeros?», one might answer «oh! You then just get two-by-two matrices and that's that». On the other hand, «oh! you just get split-octonions» in the middle of an explanation of what octonions are is not going to elicit any «ah, ok, I see» replies. Surely, it may be the case that there is some sort of *irreducible complexity* here, and nothing interesting can be said.

Comment: I'm looking through Lam's 2005 Big Book O' Stuff. He does not seem to use the word octonion, although on pages 491-492 he does talk about biquaternion algebras.

Comment: Lam is fun. Granted, it's not Game of Thrones.

Comment: @Mariano, I think the issue you're describing is that most mathematicians are happy to live without the octonions and exceptional groups.  Matrix algebras and $GL_n$ (and classical groups) are sufficient for most people's work.  The octonions and $G_2$ are not so universally studied, and maybe people think they are more difficult than they really are.  I don't think Zorn's model of the split octonions (over $Z$) is too bad at all -- just 2x2 matrices with vectors in $Z^3$ off the diagonal. Hard to get much simpler than Zorn, I think.     

Comment: @Marty, that's part it. But there is also a different angle: the split quaternions are the endorphism ring of an object one can construct "by hand" (the two dimensional vector space), and in that sense it is a simpler object than the quaternions themselves and it does not give anything new. Can one exhibit the split octonions in some such way? 

Comment: @Mariano:  Not really.  I guess my point is that matrix algebras are in general endomorphism rings of vector spaces -- the 2x2 case is just one example of the infinite family of examples of type $A_n$.  But the octonions are really connected to $G_2$ -- no way around it, no easy shortcuts.  I would still say that Zorn's split octonions are simpler than the non-split octonions.  For example, identifying a maximal order in the non-split octonions is difficult (due to Coxeter after earlier mistakes), but the maximal order in the split octonions is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}
$Suppose that $k$ is a field with $\operatorname{char}(k) \neq 2$.  Let's agree that an "octonion algebra" over $k$ is an 8-dimensional unital $k$-algebra $A$, endowed with a quadratic form $N: A \rightarrow k$, whose associated bilinear form $T(x,y) = N(x+y) - N(x) - N(y)$ is nondegenerate, and which satisfies $N(xy) = N(x) N(y)$ for all $x,y \in A$.

When $x \in A \setminus k$, the trace $\Tr(x) = T(x,1)$ and norm $N(x)$ are determined by the algebra structure: $x$ is the root of a quadratic polynomial with coefficients $-\Tr(x)$ and $N(x)$.  Hence the algebra structure determines the quadratic form $N$ in a convenient way.  One can talk about the "isomorphism class of an octonion algebra" while carrying around the quadratic form or not; it doesn't really matter.

It is an old theorem (Jacobson?  Albert?  I can't recall … check "[The Book of Involutions](http://www.ams.org/cgi-bin/bookstore/bookpromo?fn=90&isbn=0-8218-0904-0)" too) that the isomorphism class of the octonion algebra $k$ is determined by the isomorphism class of the quadratic form $N$.  Now, essentially by the Cayley–Dickson doubling process, the norm form $N$ is a Pfister form, i.e., $N$ is isomorphic to $\langle1,-a\rangle \otimes \langle1,-b\rangle \otimes \langle1,-c\rangle$ for some $a,b,c \in k$.

It is a fact about Pfister forms that when they are isotropic, they are split.  So if the norm form represents zero, then $N$ is isomorphic to $\langle1,-1\rangle \otimes \langle1,-1\rangle \otimes \langle1,-1\rangle$ and the octonion algebra is isomorphic to the split octonion algebra over $k$.

In this level of generality, the isomorphism classes of octonion algebras over $k$ are classified up to isomorphism by the Galois cohomology $H^3(k, \mu_2)$; you can see such a cohomology class too from the Pfister form perspective.  The Pfister form $\langle1,-a\rangle \otimes \langle1,-b\rangle \otimes \langle1,-c\rangle$ depends only on the square-classes of $a, b, c$, giving three classes in $H^1(k, \mu_2)$ whose cup product is the element of $H^3(k, \mu_2)$ classifying the octonion algebra.

Comment: Hi, Marty. You get around. I found some old email from Pete L. Clark saying you were good at this, for some value of `this.'

Comment: The theorem is Jacobson's; it is theorem 3.23 in [Richard D. Schafer, An introduction to nonassociative algebras, Pure and Applied Mathematics, Vol. 22, Academic Press, New York, 1966] Thanks!